# Is there an event called in React Ag Grid when the data is finished loading?

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

So, I have noticed in my ag-grid the data seems to load out of order - and thus some functions I run can not use the params.rowdata as it is null. are there any built in events in ag-grid that are triggered after all the data is loaded?

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use `firstDataRendered` Grid Event

```js
const onFirstDataRendered = (params) => console.log({ params });

...
<AgGridReact onFirstDataRendered={onFirstDataRendered} />
...
```

http://www.ag-grid.com/react-data-grid/grid-events/